# Principles behind FileStreaming

Tags: c#, wcf, filestream

I've been working on a project recently that involves a lot of `FileStreaming`, something which I've not really touched on before. 
To try and better acquaint myself with the principles of such methods, I've written some code that (theoretically) downloads a file from one `dir` to another, and gone through it step by step, commenting in my understanding of what each step achieves, like so...

**Get fileinfo object from DownloadRequest Object**

```
RemoteFileInfo fileInfo = svr.DownloadFile(request);
```

*DownloadFile method in WCF Service*

```
public RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request)
            {
                RemoteFileInfo result = new RemoteFileInfo(); // create empty fileinfo object
                try
                {
                    // set filepath
                    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(request.FilePath , @"\" , request.FileName);
                    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath); // get fileinfo from path

                    // check if exists
                    if (!fileInfo.Exists)
                        throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("File not found",
                                                                  request.FileName);

                    // open stream
                    System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath,
                              System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

                    // return result 
                    result.FileName = request.FileName;
                    result.Length = fileInfo.Length;
                    result.FileByteStream = stream;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // do something
                }
                return result;
            }
```

**Use returned FileStream from fileinfo to read into a new write stream**

```
// set new location for downloaded file
string basePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\SST Software\DSC\Compilations\" , compName, @"\");
string serverFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, file);
double totalBytesRead = 0.0;

if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);

int chunkSize = 2048;
byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

// create new write file stream 
using (System.IO.FileStream writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream(serverFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
     do
     {
        // read bytes from fileinfo stream
        int bytesRead = fileInfo.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);

        totalBytesRead += (double)bytesRead;

        if (bytesRead == 0) break;

        // write bytes to output stream
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     } while (true);

  // report end
  Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.FileName + " has been written to " + basePath + "  -  Done!");

  writeStream.Close();
}
```

What I was hoping for is any clarification or expansion on what exactly happens when using a `FileStream`. 
I can achieve the download, and now I know what code I need to write in order to perform such a download, but I would like to know more about *why* it works. I can find no 'beginner-friendly' or step by step explanations on the web. 

**What is happening here behind the scenes?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stream is just an abstraction, fundamentally it works like a pointer within a collection of data.

Take the example string of "Hello World!" for example, it is just a collection of characters, which are fundamentally just bytes.

As a stream, it could be represented to have:

1. A length of 12 (possibly more including termination characters etc)
2. A position in the stream.

You read a stream by moving the position around and requesting data.

So reading the text above could be (in pseudocode) seen to be like this:

```
do
    get next byte
    add gotten byte to collection
while not the end of the stream

the entire data is now in the collection
```

Streams are **really** useful when it comes to accessing data from sources such as the file system or remote machines.

Imagine a file that is several gigabytes in size, if the OS loaded all of that into memory any time a program wanted to read it (say a video player), there would be a lot of problems.

Instead, what happens is the program requests access to the file, and the OS returns a stream; the stream tells the program how much data there is, and allows it to access that data.

Depending on implementation, the OS may load a certain amount of data into memory ahead of the program accessing it, this is known as a **buffer**.

Fundamentally though, the program just requests the next bit of data, and the OS either gets it from the buffer, or from the source (e.g. the file on disk).

The same principle applies to streams between different computers, except requesting the next bit of data may very well involve a trip to the remote machine to request it.

The .NET `FileStream` class and the `Stream` base class, all just defer to the windows systems for working with streams in the end, there's nothing particularly special about them, it's just what you can do with the abstraction that makes them so powerful.

Writing to a stream is just the same, but it just puts data into the buffer, ready for the requester to access.

---

#### Infinite Data

As a user pointed out, streams can be used for data of indeterminate length.

All stream operations take time, so reading a stream is typically a blocking operation that will wait until data is available.

So you could loop forever while the stream is still open, and just wait for data to come in - an example of this in practice would be a live video broadcast.

Comment: Also note that the concept of a stream can be used represent an infinite sequence, e.g., the list of integers; in this case the stream does not have a fixed length.

Answer (score 1):

I've since located a book - [C# 5.0 All-In-One For Dummies](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118385365.html) - It explains everything about all `Stream` classes, how they work, which one is most appropriate and more.
Only been reading about 30 minutes, already have such a better understanding. 
Excellent guide!